# uvw map weird orientation

Tags: uv

I am quite new to unwrapping in blender.

Just wondering why these faces are pointed towards me in the UV editing, instead of lying flat?:))))
What should I do to fix this?
Thank you!

P.S. I know there is a rotate tool in the Uv editing interface, but it does not seem to help me, since it doesn't work 3-dimensionally (or at least, I couldn't get it to.)

[image]

Comment: Difficult to tell without the blend file, but it looks as if you may be missing a seam round the right-hand end of the selected part. Upload your file [here](https://blend-exchange.com/) and follow the instructions on that page so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=VW5AOX9w" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/VW5AOX9w/)

Comment: This is the link, thank you!   @JohnEason

Comment: 99% sure you didn't make a cut along the cylinder, that's why it's unwrapped circularly and stretched a lot - take the core of the toilet paper roll and try to flatten it without cutting/ripping into a ring - you can't. But with a single cut you can (and easily).

Comment: With just that part of the mesh selected (as it is in your image), unwrap with 'u' and you'll see that it unwraps fine without any further action needed. In fact you've got two edges marked along the length. You can unmark one of them before unwrapping to tidy things up.

Comment: And I've just noticed that you don't have a seam down the length of the larger diameter cylinder. If you add one to that you can select All and unwrap the lot at once.

Comment: @JohnEason  Thank you very much, everything looks fine now.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady  Thank you.